# Force IntelliJ to Keep Same-Package Import Statements

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Given the following package structure:

```
| com.java.package
    | A.java
    | B.java
```

And the following code in B.java

```
package com.java.package

public class B { 

    private final A aObject = new A();

    public void foo() {
        aObject.foo();
    }
}
```

Is is possible to include the following import line?

```
import com.java.package.A;
```

Rationale: I am writing scripts to parse file dependencies for my build system using import statements, and when dependencies are intra-package (within the same package), Android Studio (IntelliJ) will "optimize out" my import statements and remove them from the file.

Is there a way to force the IDE to keep my intra-package import statements?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you never optimize imports, then it'll probably stay.  There is a setting somewhere (varies by version) that allows you to specify how many imports of the same package before it optimizes to '*', you'll want to make that a huge number.

Ultimately, I expect IJ to optimize it away somewhere when you don't expect.  Even though it does seem to compile, it looks/feels wrong and someone else unaware of your external dependency is going to chomp it.

Better solution is to make your scripts smart enough to recognize intra-package classes as all dependencies - because implicitly they are - and just simply the problem.  What you've proposed doesn't sound like a workable solution

Comment: This is so much easier said than done. Parsing java files for `import com.bla.bla.Class` is so much easier than parsing all of Java.

Answer (score 0):

One answer is to skip trying to parse Java for imports and use the [`jdeps`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/jdeps.html) command which is part of the JDK.  `jdeps` works on `.class` files so it will work on java and kotlin (and Scala, etc).  I'm reviewing the [emerge-vis](https://github.com/glato/emerge) app, and it has the same problem with same-package imports.

*The jdeps command shows the package-level or class-level dependencies of Java class files. The input class can be a path name to a .class file, a directory, a JAR file, or it can be a fully qualified class name to analyze all class files. The options determine the output. By default, jdeps outputs the dependencies to the system output. It can generate the dependencies in DOT language (see the -dotoutput option).*